# add image from gallery to hero section

Tags: jquery, html

What I'm trying to do is have a gallery image replace the hero image on click.
I'm pretty sure there is a way to do this in jquery, but I can't find anything elegant.

I have this site http://nicholasdumais.com/jonbar/fashion/

and code:

```
<div class="col-8">
    <img class="gallery-hero" src="../img/shot7.jpg">

</div>
<div class="col-4 gallery-container">

    <span style="font-size:36px;color:#222;">
        fashion
    </span> 

    <br><br>
    <div class="col-4">
        <img class="gallery-thumb" src="../img/shot1.jpg">

        <img class="gallery-thumb" src="../img/shot3.jpg">

        <img class="gallery-thumb" src="../img/shot11.jpg">

        <img class="gallery-thumb" src="../img/shot5.jpg">

        <img class="gallery-thumb" src="../img/shot13.jpg">
    </div>


    <div class="col-4">
        <img class="gallery-thumb" src="../img/shot7.jpg">

        <img class="gallery-thumb" src="../img/shot2.jpg">

        <img class="gallery-thumb" src="../img/shot4.jpg">

        <img class="gallery-thumb" src="../img/shot9.jpg">
    </div>


    <div class="col-4">
        <img class="gallery-thumb" src="../img/shot12.jpg">

        <img class="gallery-thumb" src="../img/shot8.jpg">

        <img class="gallery-thumb" src="../img/shot10.jpg">

        <img class="gallery-thumb" src="../img/shot6.jpg">

        <img class="gallery-thumb" src="../img/shot14.jpg">
    </div>

</div>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could use something like this:

```
$('.gallery-thumb').click(function(){

  $('.gallery-hero').attr('src', $('this').attr('src'));

});
```

Or you could store larger image url in data attributes of the gallery items and use that larger file url.

Comment: This definitely seems like what I'm looking for, very elegant. The problem is it's not working for me. Is there anything specific I need to load in the html?

Comment: Well, do you have jQuery library loaded? If so, just wrap this code into <script> tag and put it somewhere in the footer on into a separate js file.

Comment: I have this loaded in the head:

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="../app.js"></script>`

and your code in app.js

I must be missing something

Comment: try to find out if your app.js file is loading and click even is getting fired with this code    
$('.gallery-thumb').click(function(){

  alert('clicked');

});

Comment: ok, it works great! I just had to load the JS at the bottom of the html file instead of the top. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Something like this.

```js
var galThamb = $('.gallery-thumb'),
    galHero = $('.gallery-hero');

galThamb.on('click', function() {
  var slfSrc = $(this).attr('src');

  galHero.removeClass('active').delay(300).queue(function(next){
    var img = new Image();
    
    img.onload = function() {
      galHero.attr('src', slfSrc).addClass('active');
    };
    
    img.src = slfSrc;
    next();
  });
});
```

```css
.gallery-hero{
  opacity: 0;
  transition: all .3s;
}

.gallery-hero.active{
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<img src="..." class="gallery-hero active">
```